# Haskell: Julia Set function

Tags: haskell, fractals

I am trying to write a function that returns the length of a Julia Set where before it passes a certain threshold, 2, with a maximum number of iterations of 255.

i have function `f z = z * z - (a :+ b)` I iterate this function over a complex number until the `magnitude` of `a + bi` crosses 2 and then count the number of iterations it took.

my first attempt was

`iter1 = genericLength . take 255 . takeWhile ((<=2) . magnitude) . iterate f`

but it is painfully slow.

my second attempt is

```
iters2 x y = iters2' f ((<=2) . magnitude) (a :+ b)
iters2' f' p c = len c 0
  where
    len c acc = if p c && acc < 255 then len (f' c) (acc + 1) else acc
```

This is still slow, considering that I will have to do millions of iterations.

Can someone help with how to make this faster?

Also,  is there `list fusion` built into the `Prelude` list functions?

Comment: How will it take millions of iterations if you cap the number of iterations at 255?

Comment: `genericLength` is (or _was_?) a somewhat silly experiment at comparing lengths with lazy number types, and horribly inefficient. In practice, it is always better to just use `length` (though of course checking lengths _at all_ is best avoided).

Comment: How are you compiling it? Have you tried profiling?

Comment: @Glubus each use of `iter` is on a pixel in a picture... so max number of iterations is `255 * height * width`

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid   `ghc --make -O2 -threaded`.  `threaded` because I am using `repa` to build a plot.  `iter1` is about 1.5x slower than `iter2`

Comment: You can also just lower the maximum allowed iterations. You're right when you say this is going to take a lot of iterations, but that's pretty much required for what you're trying to do. Im not sure if it's possible, (because I'm not too familiar with this specific function) use some sort of heuristic to predict whether or not the current pixel is going to hit the cap, and decrease the cap in that scenario (lots of fractals have big areas that all fall over the threshhold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a loop like this handcrafted recursion usually is the best approach.

Here is a comparison of three implementations:

- iter1 - original code
- iter2 - handcrafted recursion
- iter3 - @Alec's solution

The timings are (with `-O2`):

```
benchmarking julia/1
time                 17.30 μs   (17.06 μs .. 17.56 μs)
                     0.995 R²   (0.991 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 17.79 μs   (17.37 μs .. 18.51 μs)
std dev              1.839 μs   (1.008 μs .. 3.285 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 86% (severely inflated)

benchmarking julia/2
time                 1.456 μs   (1.448 μs .. 1.466 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 1.457 μs   (1.444 μs .. 1.470 μs)
std dev              42.03 ns   (34.14 ns .. 54.37 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 38% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking julia/3
time                 13.53 μs   (13.35 μs .. 13.69 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 13.42 μs   (13.26 μs .. 13.58 μs)
std dev              550.8 ns   (445.3 ns .. 768.8 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 50% (moderately inflated)
```

I think the main reason why `iter2` is better is because it avoids
allocating Complex values. In any case it does a lot fewer allocations.

Code follows:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ratio
import Data.Complex
import Criterion
import Criterion.Main

iter1 :: Double -> Double -> Complex Double -> Int
iter1 a b = genericLength . take 255 . takeWhile ((<=2) . magnitude) . iterate f
  where
   f z = z * z - (a :+ b)

iter2 :: Double -> Double -> Complex Double -> Int
iter2 a b (x :+ y) =  loop 0 x y
  where
    loop n x y
      | n > 255 || x*x + y*y > 4 = n
    loop n x y = loop (n+1)  (x*x-y*y-a) (2*x*y-b)

iter3 :: Double -> Double -> Complex Double -> Int
iter3 a b z = fst $ until (\(n,z) -> magnitude z > 2 || n == 255)
                        (\(n,z) -> (n+1,f z))
                        (0,z)
  where
   f z = z * z - (a :+ b)

-- should give 101 iterations
z0 = 7.396147400000001e-3 :+ 0.6418972592000001

main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "julia"
    [
      bench "3"  $ whnf (iter3 (negate 0.40) 0.65) z0
    , bench "2"  $ whnf (iter2 (negate 0.40) 0.65) z0
    , bench "1"  $ whnf (iter1 (negate 0.40) 0.65) z0
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: wow, I didn't realise the cost of using the Complex data type. I removed `Data.Complex` from my module and did all calculations manually and my program went from 1.6s run time for 1920x1080 to 0.2s. Thanks. I guess I should learn how to use `Criterion` too.